# Concurrent inserts into table with non-clustered GUID primary key

Tags: sql-server, blocking

I have this table on Microsoft SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_line_format]
(
    address_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_addresses_line_format PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,

    country_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_address_single_line_country FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Countries (country_id)
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
            ON DELETE NO ACTION,

    address_line NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    district_line NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

With 3.362.817 records in it.

Our application consumes messages from a queue, with 10 concurrent consumers. Each consumer inserts a line into this table, using the following statement:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Addresses_line_format] ([address_id], [country_id], [address_line], [district_line])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
```

Looking at statistics, the average elapsed time for this query is 16 seconds, which is obviously way too much.

I'm wondering if this is because of how heap tables are handling inserts like described [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/08/14/are-inserts-quicker-to-heap-or-clustered-tables.aspx), or do you have any ideas what is causing this?

I tried changing the PK to be clustered, but without any noticeable performance improvements.

Queries against the table are always performed using the following:

```
SELECT country_id, address_line, district_line
FROM Addresses_line_format
WHERE address_id = @1
```

Comment: Well, if that GUID isn't the clustered key - what ***IS*** the clustered key on that table? It should have one - a **well chosen** clustered key speeds up operations - even inserts and deletes! See Kimberly Tripp's blog post [The Clustered Index Debate Continues…](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) for a great explanation and more background

Comment: And that is most likely the problem. Now INSERT needs lookups in the IAM/PFS to determine the insert location, and those are slower than a in a clustered table. But are they THAT slower? What do you think would be a good candidate for a clustered index? Should it just be a IDENTITY column with no real use other than to determine insert locations? I've updated my question with a SELECT query sample.

Comment: My idea about the IDENTITY column might not be optimal. _"If you have a monotonically increasing column for a table that is accessed very frequently for insert operations (eg. Transaction/user activity tracking table), then creating a clustered index on that particular column can lead to performance bottlenecks."_; [Amit Banerjee](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/monotonically-increasing-clustered-index-keys-can-cause-latch-contention.aspx)

Comment: When you read Kim Tripp's blog post and all her other articles on the subject, it's clear that a **good** clustering key is **narrow, unique, static and ever-increasing** - fits perfectly to a `INT` or `BIGINT` identity

Comment: There sure is. But there are contradictions as well, given that those inserts will end up accessing the same pages.

Comment: Those insert "hotspots" were a problem in *earlier* versions of SQL Server, but according to Kim Tripp, those are **NOT** an issue really anymore, at least in SQL Server 2005 or newer. Don't let those old problems (that really aren't problems anymore) mislead you!

Comment: Oh, I see. I completely missed that. Thanks for clarifying. You can post an answer suggesting adding a identity column with a clustered index and I'll accept it.

Comment: 16 seconds for one row is too much. Judging by the order of magnitude of this problem this is not an issue of bad index keys or too many indexes. All of that is in the millisecond range. Post the actual execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if that GUID isn't the clustered key - what IS the clustered key on that table? It should have one - a well chosen clustered key speeds up operations - even inserts and deletes! See Kimberly Tripp's blog post [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) for a great explanation and more background.

When you read Kim Tripp's blog post and all her other articles on the subject, it's clear that a good clustering key is narrow, unique, static and ever-increasing - perfect fits for an `INT` or `BIGINT` identity column.

Earlier versions of SQL Server (before 2000 or 2005) did in fact have *insert hotspots* if all the inserts were happening in a single spot - those negative impacts have since been removed, those are no longer a problem, and therefore, using an `INT IDENTITY` column as your clustering key is a nearly optimal choice for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

16 seconds for one row is too much. Judging by the order of magnitude of this problem this is not an issue of bad index keys or too many indexes. All of that is in the millisecond range. Investigate the actual execution plan. You also can use SQL Profiler to trace what's being executed and how long it takes. Waiting and blocking might also be a reason it takes so long.

Comment: You are absolutely right usr. We identified another problem in our code that caused some sessions to sleep, waiting for the transaction to be committed. Solving that removed all the blocking sessions. What I discussed with @marc_s did improve performance as well though, so i'll keep that as the answer for this particular problem.